# problem with xmodmap NoSymbol

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

so my keyboard got water-damaged and subtract key(the one in the num pad area) is randomly repeating itself
so I wanted to disable the key with

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 82 = NoSymbol'
```

and when i run `xmodmap -pke | grep "keycode  82"`
it shows:
`keycode  82 =`

but unfortunately, it does not work and my subtract key is still pressing itself

any suggestions?

I'm currently using manjaro and gnome 41 and X11

Comment: Did you use `xev` to verify you have the right keycode?

Comment: yes i used xev and it gave me keycode 82 for Numpad subtract

Comment: What happens if you try to remap it to a different symbol instead of NoSymbol?

Comment: i tried that actually and it works , I remaped it to the letter e and it repeated e instead of subtract

Comment: What happens if you do `keycode 82 = NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol`? If that works, it was some modifier combination.

Comment: thanks for your answer it actually helped a little bit , subtract key does not bother me until I press another key like ctrl , then any program that I'm in thinks I'm pressing ctrl+subtract key and it minimizes itself